# Hide current Window when next Window is called in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

This problem is deriving me crazy. I do not know what's wrong, when I try to navigate between pages in my app the problem I have is :method hide() is not predefined in my pyqt5   but other can use it normally.

Whenever I use hide() or close() I have the same error which is:

> Error due to 'Ui_Login_Dialog' object has no attribute 'hide'

```
def openwindow(self):
 try:
     self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
     self.ui = Registration.Ui_Registration()
     self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
     MainWindow.hide()
     self.window.show()
 except  Exception as e:
     print("Error!", f"Error due to {str(e)}")
```

Comment: You're editing a file generated by `pyuic`, aren't you?

Comment: yes sir  it's ok ??

Comment: No you shouldn't edit `pyuic` files.  You probably don't have a reference to the MainWindow inside the scope of your method.

Comment: @alexpdev actualy the mainwindows is a dialog window which is a login interface so what i want when user click on register button  the login window close and the register show up , so i write the function in the login.py

Comment: @naratik The window type is completely irrelevnt: editing pyuic generated files is **always** discouraged and considered a ***bad*** practice. Rebuild those files, create a separate script that will be used as your main one, and follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).